# Shortest path without Dijkstra's

Tags: c++, algorithm

I need some **ideas** (not solutions) on how to go about solving the following problem. 
So there's a guy who need to get to the phones on the top right hand corner of the building. It is guaranteed they will be at that location. We have to find the shortest path he can take to get there. See the image for an example.

The first thing that came to mind was using Dijkstra's algorithm. However, I have been told that it is unnecessary and that there are simpler alternatives.

On another note, if it is a last resort option, I wouldn't mind using Dijkstra's algorithm if someone can guide me through it. I have not much prior knowledge of graph theory, although I'm competent in the language I use (C++).

[image: Staircase]

Explanation: 
He takes the escalator from the left side of the ground floor to the right side of the first floor (14 seconds);
He sprints across the first floor from the right side to the left (5 seconds);
He takes the escalator from the left side of the first floor to the right side of the second floor (13 seconds);
He takes the escalator from the right side of the second floor to the left side of the top floor (11 seconds);
He runs from the left side to the right side of the top floor (5 seconds) to claim the phone!
The total time from the front doors to the sales desk is 14+5+13+11+5=48 seconds.

The input will be specified in the following format:
Each line will each contain three integers l f r separated by single spaces, where l represents the number of seconds required to travel from the left-hand side of the current floor to the right-hand side of the floor above, f the number of seconds to run from one side of the floor to the other, and r the number of seconds to travel from the right-hand side of the floor to the left-hand side of the floor above.

Example input:

14 10 15

13 5 22

13 7 11

5

Comment: Regarding Dijkstra's algorithm: Just take a look at the animated gif on the wiki page, the only thing left to implement it would be to make a decent data structure: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm

Comment: I would like to solve it without using Dijkstra's though. Might I add that I have no prior knowledge of graph theory :(

Comment: Using Dijsktra's algorithm will probably be easier than coming up with your own, and will almost certainly be more efficient at runtime.  It's only 24 lines of fairly simple pseudocode on the Wikipedia page; you should be able to translate into C++ without a problem.

Answer (score 2):

This is a DP question.

```
f[n][left] = min{f[n-1][left] + time[go_from_left_to_right_on_floor_n-1] + time[escalator_from_right_side_up],
                 f[n-1][right] + time[escalator_from_right_side_up]}

f[n][right] = min{f[n-1][right] + time[go_from_right_to_left_on_floor_n-1] + time[escalator_from_left_side_up],
                 f[n-1][left] + time[escalator_from_left_side_up]}
```

If you want to go to third floor, left side, you can either start from the second floor, left side, go to right side, and take the escalator; or start from the second floor, right side, take the escalator. Choose the way that you use the minimum of time, and keep doing this use a loop(or recursion :) )

The solution should be **O(n)**

Comment: DP question? What does DP stand for?

Comment: @Cloud [Dynamic programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming)

Answer (score -1):

If the problem stays as small as the one you posted, I guess choyukchow's answer will work.
But if the problem gets considerably big, you may want to use heuristics. Example [here](http://www.civil.uwaterloo.ca/itss/papers%5C2006-3%20%28Review%20of%20heuristic%20SPA%29.pdf).